# Pointwise boundedness and uniform boundedness

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis

Suppose $f:[0,1]\times [1,\infty)\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ a continous function (in both variable). Let
$$
g(x)=\sup_{y\in[1,\infty)}f(x,y). (\text{Assume the supremum does exist for each x})
$$
For what kind of function $f$ is the function $g$ continuous or $g$ is bounded above?

I came to know from an old post in the stack that it is true if we replace $[1,\infty)$ by any compact interval. Also, I think there will be functions in this case for which $g$ may not be continuous. But is there any result where $f$ "nice" enough so that $g$ is continuous?

Comment: Have you checked what would happen for $f$ continuous?

Comment: @Divide1918 I think the claim is false in such case

Comment: And where exactly does it fail?

Comment: @Divide1918 I think not having  equicontinuty is an issue

Comment: And wha do you mean by equicontinuity? Doesn’t that term only apply for family of functions? In any case I think you should flesh out what you wrote in those comments in an edit to this post

Comment: @Divide1918 I think what I meant is that consider the family of function f_y(x)=f(x,y). This family needs to be equicontinuous

Comment: A simple example when $f$ is contionuous, but $g$ is not is when $f(x,y)=\sin xy$.

Comment: @AlexRavsky Yes! you are right. But if we ask a little different question say, when can $g$ be bounded above? then can we get some nice class of $f$ for which $g$ is bounded above?

Comment: The function $g$ is bounded above iff the function $f$ is bounded above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let me first drop any assumptions besides the minimal ones. Let $f: [0;1]\times[1;\infty) \to \mathbb{R}$ be any function (not necessarily continuous) such that
$$g(x) = \sup_{y\in [1;\infty)} f(x,y)$$
exists (and is finite) for all $x\in[0;1]$.

**Claim:** $f$ is bounded above if and only if $g$ is bounded above.

Indeed, if $f(x,y)\leq M$ for some fixed $M\in\mathbb{R}$ and all $x,y$, then
$$g(x) = \sup_{y\in [1;\infty)} f(x,y) \leq M.$$
Conversely, if $g(x)\leq M$ is bounded above, then
$$f(x,y) \leq \sup_{y\in [1;\infty)} f(x,y) = g(x) \leq M.$$

Notice that in particular, $g$ is not *automatically* bounded above.
What about continuity of $g$? It makes sense to request at least that $f$ is continuous in the $x$ variable. However, as has also been pointed out, $f(x,y) = \sin(xy)$ is continuous (even smooth) everywhere in both variables, but $g$ is not.
As you have mentioned in your post, the real problem here is that $y$ is not restricted to a compact interval.

I think if you want $g$ to be continuous, the most reasonable condition on $f$ is that, as you also have mentioned, that ${F} = \{f_y \mid y\in[1;\infty)\}$ is equicontinuous, where $f_y(x) = f(x,y)$. In other words,
$$\lim_{h\to 0} \left[ \sup_{f\in F} \sup_{x\in[0;1]} |f(x+h) -f(x)| \right]= 0,$$
which can be rephrased as
$$\lim_{h\to 0} \left[ \sup_{y\in [1;\infty)} \sup_{x\in[0;1]} |f(x+h,y) -f(x,y)| \right]= 0.$$
If you prefer the logical formulation, this reads
$$\forall \varepsilon > 0 \; \exists \delta > 0:\; |h| < \delta \Longrightarrow \forall y\in [1;\infty)\; \forall x\in[0;1]: |f(x+h,y) - f(x,y)| < \varepsilon$$
Now fix $\varepsilon > 0$, let $\delta > 0$ be as above and $|h|<\delta$. For fixed $x\in[0;1]$, we find $y_1, y_2\in [1;\infty)$ such that $g(x+h) < f(x+h, y_1) + \varepsilon$ and $g(x) < f(x,y_2) + \varepsilon$. Then
$$\begin{align*}
g(x+h) - g(x) &< f(x+h,y_1) - f(x,y_1) + \varepsilon < 2\varepsilon\\
g(x) - g(x+h) &< f(x,y_2) - f(x+h,y_2) + \varepsilon < 2\varepsilon
\end{align*}$$
so indeed $|g(x+h) - g(x)| < 2\varepsilon$ for fixed $x\in[0;1]$ and whenever $|h|<\delta$.

The reason equicontinuity makes this work is that we can choose $y_1, y_2$ *after* the choice of $\delta$, or, in other words, $\delta$ is independent of $y_1, y_2$.

Comment: +1) I like your explanatory style, very easy to follow!